# Get a tab delimited column in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to take data that is separated by tabs (bonus points for columns delimited by any character), and just get the first (or second, or whatever) "column" selected?

Generally speaking, I do this by pasting into excel, so I am not looking for a workaround but rather a quick way of getting a column wholly within notepad++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding Alt key should help when selecting vertical.